# Different outputs from print and a tkinter text box using a list

Tags: python, tkinter

Still new to Python, trying to figure out why when I print a function out, it displays the way I would want to display it, but in the same function updating a tkinter text box, it doesn't separate nicely with **element.split**

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

list1 = ["User1  :  1241234",
         "User2  :  32452623", 
         "User2  :  32452345"]

def func1():                              
    for element in list1:
        sep_list = element.split(':')           # SPLIT
        print(sep_list)                         # PRINT looks correct
        T1.insert("end", sep_list, 'recent')    # same update to text field, but ugly

button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Click", command=func1)  
button1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

T1 = tkinter.Text(root, height=18, width=40)
T1.place(x=35, y=35)

w = 400
h = 350
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.mainloop()
```

Print shows up as the following, which is good enough for me.

```
['User1  ', '  1241234']
['User2  ', '  32452623']
['User2  ', '  32452345']
```

While the text box gets filled with:

```
{User1  } {  1241234}{User2  } {  32452623}{User2  } {  32452345}
```

Ran through docs, tkinter pages, and SO, but don't see anything related to this. I may just be to new to understand the issue there.  Is this just an difference in which one is using the output (python vs. tkinter), any workaround there? 
This seems to occur with any list I put into the text field, gets `{ } { }` added to them on single lines.

End result I was working was get rid of the { } and have list User-Number per line.

Comment: Just curious, why do you `.split(',')` if the text does not have any commas?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mis-type.  I am actually trying to `element.split(':')` the colon, then print a list that has the **User** on first line, and the **number** on second.

Comment: `T1.insert("end", sep_list, 'recent')` attempts to insert a single-element list `sep_list` into `T`. The method `insert` expects the second parameter to be a _string_, not a list. Apparently, the curly braces is `insert`'s idea of how to handle the unexpected parameter. Pass `sep_list[0]` or some other string for best results.

Comment: @DYZ - thanks, I modified that slightly to get one working.  Ended up `for i in list1:` , `T1.insert("end", i, 'recent')`.  Still no line separations like I was shooting for, but I can look that up.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, but you should add newlines `'\n'` yourself!

Comment: Tried a simple approach to that with `T1.insert("end", (i, "\n"), 'recent')` but it brings the curly braces back.  Had to use `T1.insert("end", (i + "\n"), 'recent')`.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

DYZ has pointed out why the problem is happening, because the second parameter needs to be a string not a list (I have no idea why it adds curly braces either). However, you should be able to print the information in the format you'd like, rather than on seperate lines, by adding the elements of your list to a string, and then passing that string to the insert function. For example:

```
T1.insert('end', (list1[0] + ' ' + list1[1]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

DYZ provided some info

> T1.insert("end", sep_list, 'recent') attempts to insert a
>   single-element list sep_list into T. The method insert expects the
>   second parameter to be a string, not a list. Apparently, the curly
>   braces is insert's idea of how to handle the unexpected parameter.
>   Pass sep_list[0] or some other string for best results.

Ended up using:

```
for i in list1:
    T1.insert("end", (i + "\n"), 'recent')
```